# NSURLSession request body passed by slow NSInputStream (bandwidth management)

Tags: ios, macos, nsurlsession, nsinputstream, nsurlsessionuploadtask

Hi based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31935018/1387438) I wrote subclass of `NSInputStream` and it works pretty well.

Now It turned out that I have scenario where I'm feeding to server large amount of data and to prevent starvation of other services I need control speed of feeding data. So I improved functinality of my subclass with following conditions:

- when data should be postponed, `hasBytesAvailable` returns `NO` and reading attempts ends with zero bytes read
- when data can be send, `- read:maxLength:` allows to read some maximum amount data at once (by default 2048).
- when `- read:maxLength:` returns zero bytes read, needed delay is calculated and after that delay `NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable` event is posted.

Here is interesting parts of code (it is mixed with C++):

```
- (NSInteger)read:(uint8_t *)buffer maxLength:(NSUInteger)len {
    if (![self isOpen]) {
        return kOperationFailedReturnCode;
    }
    int delay =  0;
    NSInteger readCount = (NSInteger)self.cppInputStream->Read(buffer, len, delay);
    if (readCount<0) {
        return kOperationFailedReturnCode;
    }
    LOGD("Stream") << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
            << " len: " << len
            << " readCount: "<< readCount
            << " time: " << (int)(-[openDate timeIntervalSinceNow]*1000)
            << " delay: " << delay;

    if (!self.cppInputStream->IsEOF()) {
        if (delay==0)
        {
            [self enqueueEvent: NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable];
        } else {
            NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: delay*0.001
                                                     target: self
                                                   selector: @selector(notifyBytesAvailable:)
                                                   userInfo: nil
                                                    repeats: NO];

            [self enumerateRunLoopsUsingBlock:^(CFRunLoopRef runLoop) {
                CFRunLoopAddTimer(runLoop, (CFRunLoopTimerRef)timer, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
            }];
        }
    } else {
        [self setStatus: NSStreamStatusAtEnd];
        [self enqueueEvent: NSStreamEventEndEncountered];
    }

    return readCount;
}

- (void)notifyBytesAvailable: (NSTimer *)timer {
    LOGD("Stream") << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "notifyBytesAvailable time: " << (int)(-[openDate timeIntervalSinceNow]*1000);

    [self enqueueEvent: NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable];
}

- (BOOL)hasBytesAvailable {
    bool result = self.cppInputStream->HasBytesAvaible();
    LOGD("Stream") << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ": " << result << " time: " << (int)(-[openDate timeIntervalSinceNow]*1000);
    return result;
}
```

I wrote some test for that and it worked.

Problem appeared when I used this stream with `NSURLSession` as source of body of HTTP request. From logs I can see that `NSURLSession` tries to read everything at once. On first read I return limited portion of data. Immediately after that `NSURLSession` asks if there are bytes available (I return `NO`).
After some time (for example 170 ms), I'm sending notification that bytes are now available but `NSURLSession` doesn't respond to that and do not invoke any method of my stream class.

Here is what I see in logs (when running some test):

```
09:32:14990[0x7000002a0000] D/Stream: -[CSCoreFoundationCppInputStreamWrapper open]
09:32:14990[0x7000002a0000] D/Stream: -[CSCoreFoundationCppInputStreamWrapper hasBytesAvailable]: 1 time: 0
09:32:14990[0x7000002a0000] D/Stream: -[CSCoreFoundationCppInputStreamWrapper read:maxLength:] len: 32768 readCount: 2048 time: 0 delay: 170
09:32:14990[0x7000002a0000] D/Stream: -[CSCoreFoundationCppInputStreamWrapper hasBytesAvailable]: 0 time: 0
09:32:14990[0x7000002a0000] D/Stream: -[CSCoreFoundationCppInputStreamWrapper hasBytesAvailable]: 0 time: 0
09:32:14990[0x7000002a0000] D/Stream: -[CSCoreFoundationCppInputStreamWrapper hasBytesAvailable]: 0 time: 0
09:32:15161[0x7000002a0000] D/Stream: -[CSCoreFoundationCppInputStreamWrapper notifyBytesAvailable:]notifyBytesAvailable time: 171
```

Where time is amount of milliseconds since stream has been opened.

Looks looks `NSURLSession` is unable to handle input streams with limited data rate.
Does anyone else had similar problem?
Or has alternative concept how to achieve bandwidth management on `NSURLSession`?

Answer (score 1):

solutions tha I can support is:

1. using NSURLSessionStreamTask, from iOS9 and OSX10.11.
2. using ASIHTTPRequest instead.

Comment: `ASIHTTPRequest` is some solution (it supports throttling), but my project is to far in progress, that is is already to late to change used framework now. Also this `ASIHTTPRequest` looks like abandoned project and manageress doesn't like this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `NSInputStream` is a class cluster.  That makes subclassing hard.  And in the case of `NSInputStream`, any subclasses are completely unsupported and are likely to fail in fascinating ways.  (See http://blog.bjhomer.com/2011/04/subclassing-nsinputstream.html for details.)

Instead of subclassing `NSInputStream`, you should use a bound pair of streams and create your own data provider class to feed data into it.  To do this:

- Call `CFStreamCreateBoundPair`.
- Cast the resulting `CFReadStream` object to an `NSInputStream` pointer.
- Cast the `CFWriteStream` object to an `NSOutputStream` pointer.
- Pass the input stream when you create the upload task or request object.
- Create a class that uses a timer to periodically pass the next chunk of data to the output stream.

If you do this, the data your data provider class passes to the `NSOutputStream` will become available for reading from the `NSInputStream` on the other end.

Comment: I already have working subclass of `NSOutputStream` (which owns socket stream) which works perfectly SocketRocket and provides throttling. Same solution for `NSInputStream` doesn't work for `NSURLSession`. If I remember correctly (question is quite old) I've already tried use pair of bounded streams with same result.